# error during writing data into csv file, ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, csv

This is a code:

```
 import pandas as pd
    import csv
    with open('reviews.csv') as myFile:  
        reader = csv.reader(myFile)w
    with open('bow.csv','a',newline="") as file:
        handler= csv.writer(file)
        for rowdata in reader:
            handler.writerow({rowdata,'asd'})
```

Error is ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Answer (score 1):

`csv.reader()` can only read from an open file. When you exit the first `with` block,`myFile` is automatically closed, so `reader` can't read from it any more.

You need to keep the input file open while you read from it.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
with open('reviews.csv') as myFile:  
    reader = csv.reader(myFile)
    with open('bow.csv','a',newline="") as file:
        handler= csv.writer(file)
        for rowdata in reader:
            handler.writerow({rowdata,'asd'})
```

You can also open multiple files in a single `with` statement, so you don't need to nest them.

```
with open('reviews.csv') as myFile, open('bow.csv','a',newline="") as file:  
    reader = csv.reader(myFile)w
    handler= csv.writer(file)
    for rowdata in reader:
        handler.writerow({rowdata,'asd'})
```